# Why is the viewport shading color : texture grey instead the base color of my texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view, shaders

[image]

According to Blender Guru's tutorial it should be more like this one:

[image]

Why no color for my viewport shading??

[image]

Comment: Most likely because you've selected the bump map in the shader editor. The solid mode displays the last selected texutre node in the shader editor

Comment: oh I didn't know, thanks @Gorgious